# Unable to Postman POST to dot net API when Foreign Keys are involved c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, postman

I've made a simple warehouse management system and the site itself is running fine - but trying to do API tests with Postman POST's is not working specifically when trying to post a piece of Cargo who has two foreign keys that point to a customerID and a shipment ID.

My DB is made up of Customer, Shipment, & Cargo tables at the moment.

I can POST an actual Shipment entry via Postman as it has no foreign keys. But when I attempt to post a piece of cargo which has foreign keys of Shipment & Customer I keep being told by Postman "405 method not found"

I've created -API controllers for this specific purpose as well. And the Shipment is working just fine.

Here are two methods in the APICargoSend controller I've tried to build doing the same thing for testing purposes.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Cargo>> PostCargo(Cargo cargo)
    {
        _context.Cargo.Add (cargo);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCargo", new { id = cargo.Id }, cargo);
    }

    [HttpPost] // post method
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult>
    CargoPost(
        [
            Bind(
                "Id,TypeOfPallet,Length,Width,Height,Weight,Damage,Shipment,Customer")
        ]
        Cargo cargo
    )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Cargo.Add (cargo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCargo",
            new { id = cargo.Id },
            cargo);
        }
        return Ok("Succeeded");
    }
```

This is my cargo db model

```
    {public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Type of Pallet")]
    public PalletType TypeOfPallet { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public bool Damage { get; set; }
    public Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public enum PalletType
{
    HeatTreated,
    Wooden,
    Metal,
    Tote,
    Crate,
    SkeletonCrate,
    NonHeatTreated,
    EuropeanPallet
}
```

And here is my POSTMAN code - I've tried a variety of different ways all to no avail.

```
"Id": 20,
"TypeOfPallet": 0,
"Length": 20,
"Width": 40,
"Height": 50,
"Weight": 120,
"Damage": true,
"foreign_key": {
    "Shipment": 1,
    "Customer": 2
}
}
```

I've also done

```
{
"Id": 20,
"TypeOfPallet": 0,
"Length": 20,
"Width": 40,
"Height": 50,
"Weight": 120,
"Damage": true,
"Shipment: 1,
"Customer: 2
}
```

Unable to even hit a breakpoint when debugging and I'm seriously lost.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [Bind] and add [FromBody] to test in Postman

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CargoPost([FromBody]Cargo cargo)
```

use this data for test:

```
{
"Id": 20,
"TypeOfPallet": 0,
"Length": 20,
"Width": 40,
"Height": 50,
"Weight": 120,
"Damage": true
}
```

and fix Cargo

```
....
 public int? ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
  public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

after this you can test your data too

```
{
"Id": 20,
"TypeOfPallet": 0,
"Length": 20,
"Width": 40,
"Height": 50,
"Weight": 120,
"Damage": true,
"ShipmentId": 1,
"CustomerId": 2
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If breakpoint is not stopping your application when you try to make a POST request with POSTMAN it probably that you are making some mistake on your request.

I mean, when you send, for example, a GET request to a server - controller that doesn't have this method implemented it'll throw this error cause it hasn't found any GET Methods.

Could you post a screenshot of your postman request?